# Vim errorformat and ncvhdl

Tags: vim, errorformat

I am trying to set up my Vim environment, to be able to compile VHDL code by using the Cadence VHDL Compiler (`ncvhdl`). However, my errorformat string is not working properly. A typical `ncvhdl` error line is:

```
ncvhdl_p: *E,EXPBEG (tc_lg_and2-rtl-a.vhd,3|34): expecting the
reserved word 'BEGIN' [1.2].
```

I am setting the errorformat to:

```
set errorformat=ncvhdl_p:\ *E\\,%m\ (%f\\,%l\|%c)
```

Any hints out there?
Thanks!

Comment: Guillermo, did the solution below work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you want to do:

```
set errorformat=ncvhdl_p:\ \*%t\\,%.%#\ (%f\\,%l\\|%c):\ %m
```

- The `*` character needs to be escaped.
- Use `%t` to identify a single character indicating the error type (**E**rror/**W**arning/**L**int).
- Use `%.%#` to skip a string, like `.*` in regular expressions.

For more information:

```
:help errorformat
```

The setting `set makeprg=cat\ example.txt` can be used as a quick way of testing the `errorformat` expression if `example.txt` contains a list of error lines copied from the command output.

Comment: @GuillermoConde in that case you should mark this answer as correct.